# c++ opengl ES 2.0 App renders only wireframe on Nvidia shield tablet, but renders correctly on other devices

Tags: android, c++, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

During tests of the app on my Nvidia Shield tablet it shows only wireframes instead of filling the polygons.
Same app renders correctly (filled polygons) on my LG G6 phone, and in windows as an UWP app.
I am using Visual Studio 2019 community to code in c++, with opengl ES 2.0.
Looking into the debug settings on the tablet, I could not find anything like "force wireframe" or similar.
I have no idea which part of my code I should include in this post.
I am using android 7.0, which is the latest available for this tablet.
Anyone had the same issues, maybe on other devices as well?

Comment: Have you tried: https://github.com/google/gapid to see what is going on?

Comment: No I haven't. Looks complicated, but I will give it a try. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Found it: 
It was the pixelshader. The rounding is apparently not well implemented on the nvidia shield:

```
    gl_FragColor = vColor*smoothstep(0.0, length(fwidth(vTexcoord)), 1.0 - length(vTexcoord)); //doesn't work

gl_FragColor = vColor*smoothstep(0.0, length(fwidth(vTexcoord)), 0.9999 - length(vTexcoord)); //works
```

Comment: Is it possible that `length(fwidth(vTexcoord))` is zero? (docs for `smoothstep` say that `Results are undefined if edge0 ≥ edge1`)

Comment: yes, indeed there is something different with the rounding on Nvidia Shield. If I use 0.9999 - length(vTexcoord) for the third parameter, it works. So it was not the smoothstep function but the rounding. I also have "precision mediump float;"